# microsoft.insights/components/ProactiveDetectionConfigs in arm template force to multiple deploy

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager

I'm deploying an ARM template that take care of creating an app service plan.
I've exported the template from the existing plan and parametrized for our needs.
sometimes we get several errors on deplying

microsoft.insights/components/ProactiveDetectionConfigs

the errors are of

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: componentEnv
```

if we retry many times the operations until all the ProactiveDetectionConfigs resources are deployed we can finally complete the deployment.
Currently we have the following resources

```
microsoft.insights/components
microsoft.insights/webtests
Microsoft.Portal/dashboards
Microsoft.Web/serverfarms
microsoft.insights/components/ProactiveDetectionConfigs
Microsoft.Web/sites
```

I cannot figure out if i'm not considering some dependencies (currently is dependent on  microsoft.insights/components and  Microsoft.Web/sites) or if that kind of resource is necessary at all

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To deploy the ProactiveDetectionConfigs into ARM template use the below code in your template

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components/ProactiveDetectionConfigs",
  "apiVersion": "2018-05-01-preview",
  "name": "string",
  "location": "string",
  "properties": {
    "CustomEmails": [ "string" ],
    "Enabled": "bool",
    "RuleDefinitions": {
      "Description": "string",
      "DisplayName": "string",
      "HelpUrl": "string",
      "IsEnabledByDefault": "bool",
      "IsHidden": "bool",
      "IsInPreview": "bool",
      "Name": "string",
      "SupportsEmailNotifications": "bool"
    },
    "SendEmailsToSubscriptionOwners": "bool"
  }
}
```

Check the [ProactiveDetectionConfigs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/components/proactivedetectionconfigs?tabs=json) link for more information.

Comment: thanks for the response, the resources are created after meany retries, so I suppose the syntax is correct. I've finally fixed the problem by forcing the creation of all the ProactiveDetectionConfigs serially with dependsOn

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was transient. It worked fine in the next several deployments with no other changes.